# Python 3.3.2 - 'Grouping' System with Characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a fun little problem.

I need to count the amount of 'groups' of characters in a file. Say the file is...

```
..##.#..#
##..####.
.........
###.###..
##...#...
```

The code will then count the amount of groups of #'s. For example, the above would be `3`. It includes diagonals. Here is my code so far:

```
build = []
height = 0
with open('file.txt') as i:
  build.append(i)
  height += 1
length = len(build[0])
dirs = {'up':(-1, 0), 'down':(1, 0), 'left':(0, -1), 'right':(0, 1), 'upleft':(-1, -1), 'upright':(-1, 1), 'downleft':(1, -1), 'downright':(1, 1)}

def find_patches(grid, length):
  queue = []
  queue.append((0, 0))
  patches = 0
  while queue:
    current = queue.pop(0)
    line, cell = path[-1]
    if ## This is where I am at. I was making a pathfinding system.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a naive solution I came up with. Originally I just wanted to loop through all the elements once an check for each, if I can put it into an existing group. That didn’t work however as some groups are only combined later (e.g. the first `#` in the second row would not belong to the big group until the second `#` in that row is processed). So I started working on a merge algorithm and then figured I could just do that from the beginning.

So how this works now is that I put every `#` into its own group. Then I keep looking at combinations of two groups and check if they are close enough to each other that they belong to the same group. If that’s the case, I merge them and restart the check. If I completely looked at all possible combinations and could not merge any more, I know that I’m done.

```
from itertools import combinations, product
def canMerge (g, h):
    for i, j in g:
        for x, y in h:
            if abs(i - x) <= 1 and abs(j - y) <= 1:
                return True
    return False

def findGroups (field):
    # initialize one-element groups
    groups = [[(i, j)] for i, j in product(range(len(field)), range(len(field[0]))) if field[i][j] == '#']

    # keep joining until no more joins can be executed
    merged = True
    while merged:
        merged = False
        for g, h in combinations(groups, 2):
            if canMerge(g, h):
                g.extend(h)
                groups.remove(h)
                merged = True
                break

    return groups

# intialize field
field = '''\
..##.#..#
##..####.
.........
###.###..
##...#...'''.splitlines()
groups = findGroups(field)

print(len(groups)) # 3
```

Comment: Perfect! It works *perfectly*. But, one adjustment, you forgot to put `return groups` underneath your while loop in `findGroups`.

Comment: Right, I only made it a separate function in the very last moment ^^

Comment: While this brute-force approach works for small fields, it may become very slow for larger ones. The algorithm in my answer is much more efficient.

Comment: @Blckknght Hence my “naive solution” warning :)

Comment: I have noticed this. I bombarded your solution with 1,000 test cases using a timer module, and it was a bit slow. Otherwise, a very understandable solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your code is trying to do. Your `with` statement opens a file, but all you do is append the file object to a list before the `with` ends and it gets closed (without its contents ever being read). I suspect his is not what you intend, but I'm not sure what you were aiming for.

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to count the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) of a graph. In this case, the graph's vertices are the '#' characters, and the edges are wherever such characters are adjacent to each other in any direction (horizontally, vertically or diagonally).

There are pretty simple algorithms for solving that problem. One is to use a [disjoint set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure (also known as a "union-find" structure, since `union` and `find` are the two operations it supports) to connect groups of `'#'` characters together as they're read in from the file.

Here's a fairly minimal disjoint set I wrote to answer another question a while ago:

```
class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rank = {}
        self.parent = {}

    def find(self, element):
        if element not in self.parent: # leader elements are not in `parent` dict
            return element
        leader = self.find(self.parent[element]) # search recursively
        self.parent[element] = leader # compress path by saving leader as parent
        return leader

    def union(self, leader1, leader2):
        rank1 = self.rank.get(leader1,1)
        rank2 = self.rank.get(leader2,1)

        if rank1 > rank2: # union by rank
            self.parent[leader2] = leader1
        elif rank2 > rank1:
            self.parent[leader1] = leader2
        else: # ranks are equal
            self.parent[leader2] = leader1 # favor leader1 arbitrarily
            self.rank[leader1] = rank1+1 # increment rank
```

And here's how you can use it for your problem, using `x, y` tuples for the nodes:

```
nodes = set()
groups = UnionFind()

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for y, line in enumerate(f): # iterate over lines
        for x, char in enumerate(line): # and characters within a line
            if char == '#':
                nodes.add((x, y)) # maintain a set of node coordinates

                # check for neighbors that have already been read
                neighbors = [(x-1, y-1), # up-left
                             (x, y-1),   # up
                             (x+1, y-1), # up-right
                             (x-1, y)]   # left
                for neighbor in neighbors:
                    if neighbor in nodes:
                        my_group = groups.find((x, y))
                        neighbor_group = groups.find(neighbor)
                        if my_group != neighbor_group:
                            groups.union(my_group, neighbor_group)

# finally, count the number of unique groups
number_of_groups = len(set(groups.find(n) for n in nodes))
```